# Remove alert message from search bar with refiners

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem

In SharePoint 2019 on premise, I have a search bar that is displaying an alert when blank. The message is showing because I am using refiners and there has to be some input for the message to go away. Is there any way to hide the alert message when the search is blank, but keep the refiners on the webpart?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Note: this could potentially interfere with other functionalities of SharePoint, you can use CSS or JavaScript to manipulate the DOM elements. Heres an ex.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var alertElement = document.querySelector('.alert-class-name'); // replace '.alert-class-name' with the actual class name of your alert
    if (alertElement) {
        alertElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

Replace `'.alert-class-name'` with the actual class name of your alert.

Let me know if this helps.